# Amazon S3, Cloudfront, HTTPS doesn't load sometimes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, https, amazon-cloudfront

I have a site setup statically with an Amazon S3 bucket. I have an Elastic Beanstalk instance running my server. I also used ACM to receive a certificate to serve over HTTPS. I used cloudfront to connect this to my website.

Everything works perfectly sometimes; the site says secure, all my api calls work, and everything is awesome. However, sometimes (usually on first load after a while) the site isn't reached and ends up timing out or ends up taking 20-30 seconds to load in comparison to the usual 1-2 seconds.

Any ideas on this? Did I set something up incorrectly? I have an alias that's set up through Route 53 called api.mydomain.com that points to my elastic beanstalk instance. This is because my certificate is for mydomain.com so I had to have an api endpoint that included mydomain.com.

We're nearing beta launch and this is the last hurdle so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you trace where the delay is coming from?

Comment: We originally thought it was cause our vendor.bundle.js was 13mb so it was timing out before it loaded, but I got it down to 600kb using compression and the error is still there. It's hard to trace cause it's so random and as soon as it fails it usually refreshes or works the next time so it doesn't leave any footprints.

Could it be because we're using the free tier elastic beanstalk servers?

Comment: Why you want to go through beanstalk, rather than directly interfacing with S3 from cloudfront?

Comment: Is there an error message shown in the browser?  If so, the error and its headers should be edited into the question.  After that, your first step is probably to review the web server logs.  If the slow response times are reflected there, then CloudFront and DNS can be ruled out.